# How to Update the Record only once in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to update the field in Custom object(Agreement__c) when the task(Standard Object) status is 'Completed' but not every time.

Present Functionality : whenever task status is completed and then automatically updating the field in custom object.

I want to Update only once when the all the records in Task Status is completed( There is no more records in task object) and then has to updated the field in custom object.

Can you Please Help me.

```
public static void onAfterUpdate(List<Task> trgNew, Map<Id,Task> oldMap)
    {
        Task oldT;
        Map<Id, Agreement__c> agreementMap = new Map<Id, Agreement__c>();
        Set<Id> agreementIdSet = new Set<Id>();
       // trgNew = [Select id, type, status from task where id in: agreementIdSet and Status! = 'Completed'];
        for(Task t : trgNew)
        {

        oldT=oldMap.get(t.Id);
    if(t.Type=='Additional info needed for Legal' && t.Status=='Completed' &&  t.Status!=oldT.Status)
            {
                agreementMap.put(t.WhatId,new Agreement__c(Id=t.WhatId));
                agreementIdSet.add(t.WhatId);
            }
```

Comment: if any of you task completed first query all task and check all task completed or not, if completed then update parent record

Comment: Your title seems to not match the body of your question very precisely.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, I infer your requirements are:

> Change trigger criteria to fire when a `Task` has its `Status` updated to `'Complete'`, and all `Task` records under the same `Agreement__c` also have the status `'Complete'`.

I would start with putting some code in an `Apex Class` to get the ids of parent records which don't match:

```
public static Set<Id> getAgreementsWithIncompleteTask(List<Task> newRecords)
{
    Set<Id> whatIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task record : trigger.new) whatIds.add(record.WhatId);
    // The above two lines get you the ids for *all* parent records
    // This collection allows you to make your next query more selective

    Set<Id> agreementIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
        SELECT WhatId FROM Task
        WHERE What.Type='Agreement__c'
        AND WhatId IN :whatIds
        AND Status = 'Complete'
    ]) agreementIds.add((Id)aggregate.get('WhatId'));
    return agreementIds;
}
```

Then in your `for` loop you can omit them:

```
Set<Id> excludedParents = getAgreementsWithIncompleteTask(trigger.new);
if (/*existing criteria*/ && !excludedParents.contains(t.WhatId))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: am asking,  I want to Update only once when the all the records in Task 'Status' is completed( There is no more records in task object) and then has to updated the field in custom object. This action has to happen whenever user updated the task status is completed (last record of the task) and then automatically update the field in Agreement object

Comment: @VivekanandaReddy That sounds like what I have outlined, no?

Comment: No, this is not the right criteria....Change trigger criteria to fire when a Task has its Status updated to 'Complete', and all Task records under the same Agreement__c also have the status 'Complete'..... see my message above for requirement.